# How to show Legends for all the series data in stacked column chart Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In this chart I want to show all the people's name with it's band color as legends who has different fruits. Here Some people can have many kind of fruits but I don't want to show the name twice.Here it just shows the series name but I want to show all the people's name in the bottom.Can anyone help me with this?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges','Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series : [{
     data : [{
    x:0,
    y:3,  
    name:'John',
    color:'#FF5733'
   },
   {
    x:0,
    y:5,
    name:'Parker',
    color:'#009900'
   },{
    x:0,
    y:1,
    name:'Adam',
    color:'#95FF33'
   },{
    x:1,
    y:5,
    name:'Alex',
    color:'#E3FF33'
   },{
    x:1,
    y:3,
    name:'Pukal',
    color:'#33BDFF'
   },{
    x:1,
    y:4,
    name:'Mark',
    color:'#FB33FF'
   },{
    x:2,
    y:3,
    name:'John',
    color:'#FF5733'
   },{
    x:2,
    y:4,
    name:'Parker',
    color:'#009900'
   },{
    x:2,
    y:2,
    name:'Mark',
    color:'#FB33FF'
   }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert the data to be in the form of multiple series instead of one series, like this:

```
{
  series : [
    { name: "John", color: "#FF5733", data: [3, 0, 3] }
    { name: "Parker", color: "#009900", data: [5, 0 4] }
    .. etc ...
  ]
}
```

Then Highcharts will automatically use the person's name as the legend.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/95cbqzh1/) to show what I mean.

I transformed the data to multiple series using this code:

```
var data = [];
var seriesLookup = {};
original.forEach(function(item){
  var series = seriesLookup[item.name];
  if(!series){
    series = {
      name: item.name,
      color: item.color,
      data: [0, 0, 0]
    };
    data.push(series);
    seriesLookup[item.name] = series;
  }
  series.data[item.x] = item.y;
});
```

Then I changed the `tooltip.pointFormat` to use `series.name` instead of `point.name`

```
tooltip: {
  headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
  pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
},
```

I also used the `dataLabels.formatter` to ignore 0 values.

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
  formatter: function(){
    return (this.y!=0) ? this.y : "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sheilak that's look super awsome! I really appreciate for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just set `legendType: 'point'`:

```
series: [{
    legendType: 'point',
    data: [ ... ]
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9kqLsfza/